# Check if value from one dataframe exists in another dataframe, print all pairs of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 DataFrames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['11', '12', '13', '14'],
                    'name': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20'],
                    'name': ['a',   'a', 'b',  'c',  'c',  'c']})
```

I need to build a matrix that will consist of all pairs of codes of the same names from two DataFrames.
The matrix should look like this:

```
pairs  value from df1     value from df2
a-a       11                15
a-a       11                16
a-a       12                15
a-a       12                16
b-b       13                17
c-c       14                18
c-c       14                19
c-c       14                20
```

Appreciate any help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='name', suffixes=(' from df1',' from df2'))
df.insert(0, 'pairs', df['name'] + '-' + df.pop('name'))
print (df)
  pairs code from df1 code from df2
0   a-a            11            15
1   a-a            11            16
2   a-a            12            15
3   a-a            12            16
4   b-b            13            17
5   c-c            14            18
6   c-c            14            19
7   c-c            14            20
```

Comment: What's the difference between `how='outer'` and `how='inner'` here?